# Split a vector of strings over a character to return a matrix

Tags: regex, r, string

I have

```
rownames(results.summary)
[1] "2 - 1" "3 - 1" "4 - 1"
```

What I want is to return a matrix of

```
2  1
3  1
4  1
```

The way Ive done it as:

```
for(i in 1:length(rownames(results.summary)){
  current.split <- unlist(strsplit(rownames(results.summary)[i], "-"))
  matrix.results$comparison.group[i] <- trim(current.split[1])
  matrix.results$control.group[i] <- trim(current.split[2])
}
```

The trim function basically removes any whitespace on either end.

I've been learning regex and was wondering if there's perhaps a more elegant vectorized solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
vv <- c("2 - 1", "3 - 1", "4 - 1")
matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(vv, " - "))), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    1
# [2,]    3    1
# [3,]    4    1
```

Comment: Nice, what if in between the strsplit, I still wanted to trim all whitespace?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The way I've written it does trim the whitespace (see the output of `strsplit(vv, " - ")`), but even if it didn't there's no whitespace in the final numeric matrix.

Answer (score 6):

No need to use `strsplit`, just read it using `read.table`:

```
 read.table(text=vec,sep='-',strip.white = TRUE) ## see @flodel comment
  V1 V2
1  2  1
2  3  1
3  4  1
```

where vec is :

```
vec <-  c("2 - 1", "3 - 1", "4 - 1")
```

Comment: Why would this return a numeric and integer column respectively?

Comment: ... It looks like `type.convert` is not treating trimming consistently: `type.convert("1 ")` is numeric but `type.convert(" 1")` is integer.

Comment: Looks like `strip.white = TRUE` can fix that.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `scan`

```
vec <-  c("2 - 1", "3 - 1", "4 - 1")
s <- scan(text = vec, what = integer(), sep = "-", quiet = TRUE)
matrix(s, length(s)/2, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    1
# [2,]    3    1
# [3,]    4    1
```

Another option is `cSplit`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(data.frame(vec), "vec", sep = " - ", fixed=TRUE)
#    vec_1 vec_2
# 1:     2     1
# 2:     3     1
# 3:     4     1
```

Comment: (+1) for the all mighty `cSplit`

Comment: But I also just noticed that the columns from `cSplit` are character, not numeric

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Richard, I've added a `type.convert` argument to `cSplit` (defaults to `TRUE`), so if you run this again, it should come out as integer values, not character. This is with splitstackshape V1.4.2, [now on CRAN](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/splitstackshape/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_match` from the package `stringr` for this:

```
library(stringr)
##
x <- c("2 - 1","3 - 1","4 - 1")
##
cmat <- str_match(x, "(\\d).+(\\d)")[,-1]
> apply(cmat,2,as.numeric)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    3    1
[3,]    4    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `reshape2` `colsplit`

```
library(reshape2)
colsplit(x, " - ",  c("A", "B"))
#   A B
# 1 2 1
# 2 3 1
# 3 4 1
```

Or using `tidyr`s `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(data.frame(x), x, c("A", "B"), sep = " - ")
#   A B
# 1 2 1
# 2 3 1
# 3 4 1
```